# How to make my bottom navbar disappear when the keyboard is appearing React Native Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

When I click on a text input and the keyboard pops up, how do I make the navbar disappear/hide?
[image: Red part should be invisible]

The navbar in red should disappear when the keyboard appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just be careful, that if you are using React Navigation 6x whole `tabBaroptions` prop was removed and options were renamed.

see docs below:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-5.x/#the-tabbaroptions-prop-is-removed-in-favor-of-more-flexible-options-for-bottom-tabs

```
keyboardHidesTabBar -> tabBarHideOnKeyboard
```

You have two options in your tab Navigator:

`screenOptions` => works for all screens inside navigator, no need to define options

```
<Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true}}>
<Tab.Screen name={"my first screen"} /> 
<Tab.Screen name={"my second screen"} /> 
</Tab.Navigator>
```

`options` => works only for current screen

```
<Tab.Navigator>
<Tab.Screen name={"my first screen"} options={{tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true}}/> 
<Tab.Screen name={"my second screen"} /> 
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked i had the version 5 for this app :)

Comment: Glad it helped, please accept it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `keyboardHidesTabBar: true` inside `tabBarOptions` it will hide bottom navigation bar when keyborad is open.